# aws s3 intergration with mediawiki

Tags: amazon-s3, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I working with mediawiki.
I want to change upload directory path to aws s3, i tried these two extensions but i getting some warning message.

I dont know these extension are working correctly.

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LocalS3Repo and
 https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AWS

If anybody is working with these extension or if you achieved these in any other ways 
please explain me

Answer (score 1):

I have been succesfully using the method described [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User%3aChillum/Integration_with_S3), though in step 6, rather than using an apache rewrite, I changed the image paths in `LocalSettings.php`.

(It was quite a lot of work though, and I never figured out a way to the the `cache-control` and `expires` headers on the files, which was the real reason why I wanted to do it to begin with.)

Comment: Is the method an old way and the extension LocalS3Repo the new way of doing this? Is the extension better?

Comment: @nischayn22 I might be wrong, but it seems like LocalS3Repo is no longer maintained?

Comment: @leo I am using it now, needed some changes for it to work for me. Thanks for the heads up :)